# Rails Image on Paypal Button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, paypal

we have an paypal button in our website and try to change the image to an image url from databse.

I have the following code:

```
<form id="paypal" desc="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input id="" desc="" type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input id="" desc="" type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="U3NMECR2XZPWS">
<input id="" desc="paypImgInp" type="image" src="assets/{{option('purchase_image')}}" border="0" name="submit" alt="Jetzt einfach, schnell und sicher online bezahlen – mit PayPal.">
<img id="" desc="paypImg" alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/de_DE/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
```

The literal `{{code}}` will be evaluated as function call.
This means in this case that `{{option('purchase_image')}}` will load the image name for paypal from database (see image here: http://puu.sh/7mm4I/606876d711.png )

with "assets" this works only in my widgets-controller (because this is a widget which will be shown), but not on start page, news article or else...

How i have to write the code for this?
i´ve found `image_tag(name)` but this doesnt work here because its not an image.
How to render the url to the real image? (stored unter `app/assets/images/btn_donate_SM.gif` )

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly, image_path should give you the relative path to the image:

```
<%= image_path(option('purchase_image')) %>
```